# planes and lines and circles

Tags: geometry

Consider the points $A(1,2,3)$, $B(-2,3,-1)$ and $C(3,1,-2)$.

$a)$ write an equation of plane $ABC$

$b)$ show that $O$ is on the axis ($\delta$) of circle $S$ circumscribed about triangle $ABC$

I have solved part $a$, and the answer I got was $-9x-23y+z+50=0$. 
I just need help solving part $b$.

Comment: what does an axis of a circle means?

Comment: What do you mean $O$ is on the axis? do you mean on the diameter of the circle? Assuming your plan function is right, $O$ is not even  on the plan ABC. Is your $O$ the original point (0,0,0)?

Comment: -9-46+3+50=-2, so (A) isn't on your plane

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1)  Let $r$ the line  passing thorough the origin and orthogonal to the plane:
$$
r) \qquad (x,y,z)^T=t(-9,-23,1)^T
$$

2)  intersect this line with the plane and find the point $O$.

3) verify if the distances from $O$ to the points $A,B,C$ are the same.